# Why is Angular 7 App having more string objects in heap in comparison to AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, angular

```
{
  "name": "ClientApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "2.2.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26",
    "angular": "1.5.5",
    "angular-animate": "1.5.5",
    "angular-aria": "1.5.7",
    "angular-cookies": "1.5.5",
    "angular-mocks": "1.5.5",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.5.5",
    "angular-scroll": "1.0.2",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap": "1.3.3",
    "angular-ui-grid": "4.0.4",
    "angular-ui-router": "1.0.3",
    "animate": "1.0.0",
    "animate.css": "3.5.2",
    "jquery-ui": "1.12.1",
    "jquery.inputmask": "3.3.4",
    "lodash": "4.17.11",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "moment": "2.13.0",
    "ng-mask": "3.1.1",
    "spin.js": "2.3.2",
    "stacktrace-js": "2.0.0",
    "toastr": "2.1.2",
    "waypoints": "4.0.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "7.1.1",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^6.0.1",
    "ngx-page-scroll": "5.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "9.1.1",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
    "@types/angular": "1.6.51",
    "@types/core-js": "2.5.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "10.12.11",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "css-loader": "0.8.0",
    "file-loader": "2.0.0",
    "imports-loader": "0.8.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "style-loader": "0.8.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6",
    "url-loader": "1.1.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

I had an app which was in Angular JS 1.5, Now we decided to migrate it. As part of the initial analysis, I was doing a simple POC with just 10-15 components which don't have any complex business logic. I did copy a couple of styles from the previous app and that's about it. With just these 15 components when I build the new app with

```
ng build --prod  --vendor-chunk --sourceMap=false --
```

I realized Angular 7 app has a very high heap size in comparison to our existing Angular JS based application. The major difference comes out from string objects which is very large in Angular 7, I just want to understand is this normal for Angular 7 or am I missing here anything.

Also with `--aot` option, the heap size is even more. We do have a couple of requirements like open in a new window (which again loads all app in new chrome tab with a different route). I am afraid if the user will open 3 or more tabs memory will reach around a Gb.

Is there any way we can minimize the run time heap memory especially these strings? I am attaching images from Chrome Dev Tools and my angular.json file here.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ClientApp": {
      "root": "ClientApp",
      "sourceRoot": "ClientApp",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "wwwroot/clientapp/dist",
            "index": "ClientApp/index.html",
            "main": "ClientApp/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "ClientApp/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "ClientApp/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "ClientApp/favicon.ico",
              "ClientApp/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "Content",
                "ignore": [ "*.js", "*.css" ],
                "output": "Content/"
              },
            ],
            "styles": [
              "ClientApp/styles.css",
              "Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css",
              "Content/dmsglobalstyles.css",
              "Content/styles-extension.css",
              "Content/responsive-styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "ClientApp/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "ClientApp/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": false,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "aot": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "ClientApp/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "ClientApp/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "ClientApp/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "ClientApp/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "ClientApp/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "ClientApp/favicon.ico",
              "ClientApp/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "ClientApp/tsconfig.app.json",
              "ClientApp/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ClientApp-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ClientApp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "ClientApp:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ClientApp"
}
```

[image]

[Dev Build Bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TCO4.png)

Comment: Which version of `rxjs` is used? Because there was a bug in `rxjs 6.3.3` which could lead to memory leaks.

Comment: I am using the same version , should I downgrade it ? I have also added my package.json for reference .

Comment: Try either downgrading to version `6.3.2` or upgrading to version `6.4` and compare the results.

Comment: That didn't help still the string size is same around 26 Mb in heap. There is no memory leak upon interaction/routing away however the initial size itself is coming this one.  RxJs has problems with observable subscriptions which is not the case here I guess.  Most of these string objects are either relates to css, html or angular internal files.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! So your "proof of concept" uses ngUpgrade? References all of Angular *and* AngularJS *and* jquery *and* ngrx? Consider scaling back to *just Angular* and then add each of the other libraries one at a time. That may give you a better sense of which of these many things could be causing the issue.

Comment: @DeborahK Thank you it's please talking to you , I have refereed multiple videos of yours before starting this Angular 7 POC . Yes we are planning to use ngUpgrade as we can not migrate all at once .  So far what I have found each component that I have defined in angular 7 (html, css, ts) are creating these strings in the heap and also duplicating  bootstrap and JQuery multiple times. Is this how it will work , most of those components are not even in View . I have tried removing Bootstrap and it did help a bit. Still I am unable to understand why those strings are sitting in heap.

Comment: @DeborahK Moreover these strings looks exactly as I have defined in my code. Seems to me like metadata, is this how Angular 7 works , do we have any way to minimize /disable these strings not to be created in heap. My fear is if we have 200 components then It will have 200x strings per html per css and per ts file in the heap. I am sure there would be a better way of doing this.

Comment: This article may also help (or others on his blog, he's one of the Angular team members): https://blog.mgechev.com/2017/01/17/angular-in-production/

Comment: Hi, as @DeborahK brought your question to my attention, I was curious about what is going on here. Can you help me getting a more complete picture here?
first, add the option `----statsJson=true` to your build command.
After that, use something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to analyze that output, and report the findings back here please

Comment: I asked you to do that, because I believe it's a bundling/build problem. Not really an Angular one.

Comment: @sanderElias I have posted the image Dev Build Bundle . I couldn't get  anything from there which can justify why I had those string objects in heap .  Do you think anything is wrong here ?

Comment: No, that bundle should not result in a 27Meg strings. I quickly checked a number of medium to large angular apps, (also one that did run both, Angular+AngularJS).
they all level out under 8M. I have no idea yet. Would it be possible that I can get my hands on your project so I can look into it? A public reproduction repo would be ideal.